# Discord.py how to get the widget infos?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm unable to get the info of the guild widget using that code:

```
print(ctx.guild.widget.invite_url)
print(ctx.guild.widget.created_at)
```

I receive that error:

```
'function' object has no attribute 'invite_url'
```

Thank you in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call and `await` the method:

```
widget = await ctx.guild.widget()
print(widget.invite_url)
print(widget.created_at)
```